# jpeg bytes to hex value

Tags: java, android, arrays, jpeg, mjpeg

I'm receiving a stream via uvc, which gives me each mjpeg stream.

When writing the jpeg frame into a bitmap, the byte array viewed from the debugger looks like this :

```
{ 0, -128, 1, -128, 0, -128, .......}
```

I create the file by doing this:

```
bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(frame);
File file = new File(Constants.CAPTURE_PATH, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg");
file.createNewFile();
out = new FileOutputStream(file);

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
```

After I create the file and look inside it with a hex viewer, the file looks like this :

```
FF D8 FF E0 00.....
```

Does this mean that {0} became FF, and {-128} became D8?

What rules made this happen? Any help will be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that you are looking at the JPEG file header if these are the very first bytes in the file as seen by the file hex viewer. `FF D8 FF` look strikingly similar. See [here](http://www.file-recovery.com/jpg-signature-format.htm) for example and wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_files).

I'd expect that data you are looking at in the debugger is the raw *image* data which won't include the header.

Comment: Those bytes were streamed from the webcam directly, and all I do is get the frame(byte array), and write the bytes into the file. Does this mean that the header is generated automatically, which has nothing to do with the above raw bytes?

Comment: My purpose is finding the 18th, 19th byte of the jpeg image within the frame, which means I have to find FFD8 first, but no luck yet.

Comment: Header files are almost always generated automatically. I was actually looking up the bitmap header as this answer was posted.  To see the actual data you would have to start looking from offset 0x201 then add 18/19 etc from there

Comment: @JLegendre Thanks, but how should I compare those bytes? The vender says that it should be 0x40 for each of those but as on the question above, I can't figure out how to match 0x40 with those raw java bytes.

Comment: @March3April4 The last line of your code sample is the clue `bitmap.compress()`. You are writing a compressed bitmap to the file output stream you created in the previous line. The bytes you see in the debugger will have been de-compressed from what ever compression method was used by the web cam I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

After our brief conversation in the comments, I feel like this is the information you are looking for.

What you are actually looking at is the file header.  A header is essentially a block of code at the beginning of a file that tells the computer what it is so it knows what to do with it.

More info on file headers: https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/H/header.html

Now, to your specific problem.  With jpegs (just like any other file) they have their own headers and way of data organization.  The JPEG header starts with `FF D8` which to a jpeg file reader means SOI (start of image). It then goes to `FF E0` which means APP0 (Application segment).  And the list goes on.

More on jpeg files: https://web.archive.org/web/20120403212223/http://class.ee.iastate.edu/ee528/Reading%20material/JPEG_File_Format.pdf

What you will need to do is jump past the header and start looking for your "actual" data. The somewhat tricky part of jpeg file headers is that they are not all the same size so you will need to look for the SOS (start of scan) marker if I'm not mistaken and go from there.